# How to open word document inside form in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to open a word document in a panel control of Windows Forms Application to view/edit file and save.

i use this statement :

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string strclassName, string strWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetParent(int hWndChild, int hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(
        int hWnd,               // handle to window
        int hWndInsertAfter,    // placement-order handle
        int X,                  // horizontal position
        int Y,                  // vertical position
        int cx,                 // width
        int cy,                 // height
        uint uFlags             // window-positioning options
    );

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "MoveWindow")]
    static extern bool MoveWindow(
        int hWnd,
        int X,
        int Y,
        int nWidth,
        int nHeight,
        bool bRepaint
    );

    const int SWP_DRAWFRAME = 0x20;
    const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
    const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;
    const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x4;
    const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x20;
    ToolsComponents.MSWord word = new ToolsComponents.MSWord();

    private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        word.CreateWordDocument();
        word.OpenFile(@"C:\Users\ME\Documents\test.docx", true);
        int wordWnd = FindWindow("Opusapp", null);
        if (wordWnd != 0)
        {
            int ret = SetParent(wordWnd, pnlShowForm.Handle.ToInt32());

            //int ret2 = FindWindow("Opusapp", null);
            //ret = SetParent(wordWnd, pnlShowForm.Handle.ToInt32());
            SetWindowPos(wordWnd, pnlShowForm.Handle.ToInt32(), 0, 0, pnlShowForm.Bounds.Width - 20, pnlShowForm.Bounds.Height - 20, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_DRAWFRAME);
            MoveWindow(wordWnd, -5, -33, pnlShowForm.Bounds.Width + 10, pnlShowForm.Bounds.Height + 57, true);
        }
    }

    private void frmDocumentManager_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (word != null)
        {
            word.CloseDoc(true);
            word.Quit();
        }
```

but this is not a good solution and have problem in runtime.
in sometimes MS word and document started outside the form and i can't control this.

Comment: It would make much more sense (and be *a heck of a lot easier*) to fire up Word to edit the document, and grab the saved file after it's closed.